# How can I determine whether or not a card is credit or debit in Braintree?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using the **Braintree PHP SDK** and I'm unable to figure out if a card is a debit card or not.

Is it possible to know if the card is debit or credit?

Answer (score 0):

If you store a credit card with Braintree, the response will include [**BIN Database information**](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/reference/response/credit-card)

> **country_of_issuance** - The country that issued the credit card.
>
> **debit** - whether the card is a debit card.

Possible values:

```
Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::Yes
Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::No
Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::Unknown
```

Comment: From the response i get this : [debit] => Unknown,So if it is a debit will i get [debit] => Yes??

Comment: What do you get as `cardType`?

Answer (score 0):

If you create braintree `token` by passing the `customer_id` and `paymentmethod` follow the link: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/start/hello-server. From this token you can find the `cardtype`.

```
 $paymentMethod = Braintree_PaymentMethod::find('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

I work as a developer at Braintree. Calling `debit` on a payment method returns `Unknown` if we cannot determine the type from the BIN number; but, generally speaking, calling `debit` will return ‘Yes’ if it is a debit card.